# Display firebase data with react

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to react, so please give me some slack. I'm trying to extract data from a collection in firebase based on the url and display it on the page. My attempt is below:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, map } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { db } from "../../firebase";
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

export default function UserPage() {
  const { userUrl } = useParams();
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  const docUserInfo = doc(db, "userinfo", userUrl);

  useEffect(() => {
    getDoc(docUserInfo).then((doc) => {
       setUser(doc.data());
    });
  });

  return (
    <>
       <div>
        {user.map((user) => (
          <div>{user.title}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I get an error saying:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

According to other posts here, this error suggests that my object (user) is not an array, and it doesn't seem to be. I tried using typeof to understand what type of object it is, but it just says "object". So I checked using `Array.isArray()`, which returns false, but here is where I get stuck.

Using `setUser(doc.data().title)` gives me what I want, sort of, but I want all the items inside the user array and don't want to create a `useState` for all of them. I also don't think there is an issue with `useParams()`.

In addition, sometimes undefined is returned and sometimes this is done in an infinite loop, but I haven't figured out exactly when this happens.

Lastly, there are a lot of tutorials for exactly what I'm trying to do, but all of them are just displaying the fetched data in in the console (which I'm able to do), or they are using firebase<v9.

Answer (score 0):

Your code loads a single document from Firestore, so there's no need to loop over multiple users as you'd do with the `user.map` that you have. Instead, just display the properties from your `user` state variable:

```
return (
  <>
     <div>
      <div>{user.title}</div>
    </div>
  </>
);
```

Comment: so this is what I tried first, but this just gives me another error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')

Comment: That's a different problem. It sounds like there may not be a document for a users, so you'll have to handle that too.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I'm getting the correct info if I just console.log(doc.data().title) just fine, or setUser(doc.data().title).

Comment: That's **once** the data is loaded from the database, but *until* that happens your `user` state variable is `undefined`. You can either initialize it in `const [user, setUser] = useState({ title: '<none>' });`, or handle the undefined your rendering code.

Comment: ah thanks! I added [] instead:
const [user, setUser] = useState([])
 which did the trick!